# Apple timeline style scrolling on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, slideshow, transform

I would like to build a slider like Apple did: http://www.apple.com/30-years/

I have no idea how to scroll on mouseover like on the link above. I know I have to decrease the translateX value by X, but what is X? :)

```
// scroll animation
function scrollAnimation(){
$('ul').css({
'transform' : 'translateX(-' +mouseX+ 'px)'
});
scrollAnimation();
}
```

I would like to scroll the images continuosly, with a speed what depends from the mouse's position.

Here is my full code: http://jsfiddle.net/M8cnV/light/

I'm new here, so I appreciate any comments about my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I came up with:

http://jsfiddle.net/5nTpS/

I added some new variables to keep track of how far from the left or right edge the cursor is, which direction to scroll and how fast to scroll:

```
var scrollSpeed = 0;
var hotEdgeWidth = 200;
var animationSign = "-";
```

And modified your mousemove function so that it works out if the cursor is close enough to the left or right of the container that you want the images to scroll, which direction you want them to scroll in, and how fast you want them to scroll:

```
$(container).mousemove(function(e) {
    if(e.pageX > $(this).width() - hotEdgeWidth){
        scrollSpeed = hotEdgeWidth - ($(this).width() - e.pageX);
        animationSign = "-";
    }
    else if(e.pageX < hotEdgeWidth){
        scrollSpeed = hotEdgeWidth - e.pageX;
        animationSign = "+";
    }
    else{
        scrollSpeed = 0;
    }
    scrollAnimation();
    }).mouseout(function(e){
         scrollSpeed = 0;
});
```

Then, change scrollAnimation to use the .animate function, and add a complete function to call the scrollAnimation function again once the animation has finished. It only animates if no animation is already happening to prevent a feedback loop happening:

```
function scrollAnimation(){
    if (!$('li').is(':animated')){                
        $( "li" ).animate({ 
            "left": animationSign + "="+scrollSpeed+"px" 
        },
        500,
        function(){
            scrollAnimation();
        });
    }
}
```